# my thesis saved, open again, only a little content left, the file is same size

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

My thesis saved, open again, only a little content left, the file is still same size, but only several words left, still 610 Kb, but only 300 words. i spent a whole night without sleep, please help me!!! please!!

Comment: There are various ideas here http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-ways-to-recover-a-corrupted-word-document/. Make sure you make a copy first! Is the document a .docx or .doc? What version of Word?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of tricks to access the document a different way aside from your word processor.

A) Open the docx or odt file as an archive in 7-Zip, if you have it installed:

1. Right click the file
2. Hover over "7-Zip"
3. Extract the archive
4. Open the content.xml file in Notepad
5. Check for a line in the document with your thesis

B) Open the file itself in Notepad:

1. Open it in Notepad
2. Most of the file will be encrypted symbols, but there may be a line with your thesis in pure English

B worked for me when my document was corrupted when Microsoft Word crashed. It was unrecoverable in Word, but somehow the last saved text was found in Notepad.